# Nginx how to disable fastcgi retries

Tags: nginx, fastcgi

How can I disable any retries from occurring with fastcgi?

I've set:

```
fastcgi_next_upstream off;
fastcgi_next_upstream_tries 1;
```

within the nginx config.

Here are some nginx logs:

```
php_1  | 172.20.0.2 -  28/May/2018:10:07:56 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
web_1  | 172.20.0.1 - - [28/May/2018:10:07:58 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 18 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (pc-x86_64-linux-gnu) Siege/4.0.4"
php_1  | [28-May-2018 10:07:58.106908] DEBUG: pid 1, fpm_pctl_perform_idle_server_maintenance(), line 379: [pool www] currently 5 active children, 0 spare children, 5 running children. Spawning rate 1
php_1  | 172.20.0.2 -  28/May/2018:10:07:57 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
web_1  | 172.20.0.1 - - [28/May/2018:10:07:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 18 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (pc-x86_64-linux-gnu) Siege/4.0.4"
php_1  | [28-May-2018 10:07:59.108072] DEBUG: pid 1, fpm_pctl_perform_idle_server_maintenance(), line 379: [pool www] currently 5 active children, 0 spare children, 5 running children. Spawning rate 1
php_1  | 172.20.0.2 -  28/May/2018:10:07:57 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
php_1  | 172.20.0.2 -  28/May/2018:10:07:57 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
php_1  | 172.20.0.2 -  28/May/2018:10:07:57 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
web_1  | 172.20.0.1 - - [28/May/2018:10:07:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 18 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (pc-x86_64-linux-gnu) Siege/4.0.4"
web_1  | 172.20.0.1 - - [28/May/2018:10:07:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 18 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (pc-x86_64-linux-gnu) Siege/4.0.4"
web_1  | 172.20.0.1 - - [28/May/2018:10:07:59 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 18 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (pc-x86_64-linux-gnu) Siege/4.0.4"
php_1  | 172.20.0.2 -  28/May/2018:10:07:58 +0000 "GET /index.php" 200
web_1  | 172.20.0.1 - - [28/May/2018:10:08:00 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 18 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (pc-x86_64-linux-gnu) Siege/4.0.4"
php_1  | [28-May-2018 10:08:00.109179] DEBUG: pid 1, fpm_pctl_perform_idle_server_maintenance(), line 379: [pool www] currently 5 active children, 0 spare children, 5 running children. Spawning rate 1
```

Here are some results from the siege http load testing tool:

```
Transactions:                114 hits
Availability:              88.37 %
Elapsed time:              79.02 secs
Data transferred:           0.00 MB
Response time:             51.59 secs
Transaction rate:           1.44 trans/sec
Throughput:             0.00 MB/sec
Concurrency:               74.43
Successful transactions:         114
Failed transactions:              15
Longest transaction:           61.11
Shortest transaction:          28.07
```

The backend is a php-fpm service with a `max_children` setting of 5 - so it should be able to handle 5 requests concurrently maximum. However nginx seems to be 'retrying' the request if it fails (because it's reaching a concurrency amount higher than 5  - as it shows in the siege results).

A complete docker project with the above behavior can be found here: https://github.com/chrissound/phpfpmmaxchildrentest/

Answer (score 0):

I had to set `listen.backlog` to 0 within `php-fpm` as it seems to have a request queue. Though this does not seem to work completely (though it does have some effect): [How can I force fastcgi / php-fpm to refuse connections once it reaches it's capacity?](https://serverfault.com/questions/914409/how-can-i-force-fastcgi-php-fpm-to-refuse-connections-once-it-reaches-its-cap)